# Tumblr API PHP Array response into usable code in HTML and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, tumblr

```
Array ( 
    [meta] => Array ( 
    [status] => 200 [msg] => OK ) 
    [response] => Array ( 
        [user] => Array ( 
            [name] => paulkin360 
            [likes] => 0 
            [following] => 2 
            [default_post_format] => html 
            [blogs] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [name] => paulkin360 
                    [url] => http://paulkin360.tumblr.com/ [
                    [followers] => 0 
                    [primary] => 1 
                    [title] => Untitled 
                    [description] => 
                    [admin] => 1 
                    [updated] => 1379175176 
                    [posts] => 2 
                    [messages] => 0 
                    [queue] => 0 
                    [drafts] => 0 
                    [share_likes] => 1 
                    [ask] => 
                    [tweet] => auto 
                    [facebook] => auto 
                    [facebook_opengraph_enabled] => Y [type] => public 
                ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

So far that is what I have but I would want to reorganise this in html

Comment: Try wrapping your `print_r` in `<pre>` tags to get a more readable array output. `echo '<pre>', print_r($yourArray), '</pre>';`

Comment: What do you actually want it to look like?

Comment: It should display info in an html document inorder from the site name, link and the rest of the info.

Comment: What i would love to do is to pick out certain things from the array and the display them in a nice html layout

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here? You already have the array you can just echo the values in your html like. <?php echo variable['response']['user']['name']; ?> etc.

Comment: The response i get is blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of usage to get you started, you'll need to build the actual HTML yourself.

```
<?php
$user = $your_array['response']['user'];
?>

<div>Name: <?php echo $user['name']; ?></div>
<div>Likes: <?php echo $user['likes']; ?></div>
<div>Following: <?php echo $user['following']; ?></div>

<?php foreach($user['blogs'] as $blog): ?>
<div class="blog">
    <div>Name: <?php echo $blog['name']; ?></div>
    <div>URL: <?php echo $blog['url']; ?></div>
    <div>Followers: <?php echo $blog['followers']; ?></div>
    <div>Title: <?php echo $blog['title']; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```